# Why does `reject()` method on a Laravel Collection return an associative array in this case?

Tags: php, laravel

Why does `reject()` transform the items in this collection into an associative array?

```
>>> collect([1, 2, 'X', 4])->reject('X')->all();
=> [
     0 => 1,
     1 => 2,
     3 => 3,
   ]
>>>
```

Comment: Additionally to the answer below, you can simply chain `->values()` after `->all()` to reindex the array (if you need `0, 1, 2` instead of `0, 1, 3`; depends on use case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`collect()->reject` is built on `collect()->filter`, which in turn uses [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). (`Arr::where` is just an easy way to use the array_filter callback)

```
/**
 * Run a filter over each of the items.
 *
 * @param  callable|null  $callback
 * @return static
 */
public function filter(callable $callback = null)
{
    if ($callback) {
        return new static(Arr::where($this->items, $callback));
    }

    return new static(array_filter($this->items));
}
```

As mentioned in the documentation, `Array keys are preserved, and may result in gaps if the array was indexed. The result array can be reindexed using the array_values() function.` If there are no array keys specified, it uses the default 0->n. Collections apparently don't remove the indexes when it comes back from array_values();

Comment: Thank you for posting the source!